# keyboard doesn't work in grub

Tags: grub2

I cannot use my keyboard to select an OS in grub....the arrow keys, page up/down, tab, c, e...nothing works.  Actually, I can't even use the keyboard to get to BIOS...typically, I hit F12, but that doesn't work either.

The keyboard works fine when Ubuntu is up, but unfortunately, I cannot access anything on Windows, or boot from a stick.

I've tried updating grub; that doesn't work. I've also tried several other keyboards, including a wireless one. Any ideas?

Apparently, this is grub 2.02 beta 2-36 unbuntu3.1.  I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: replacing the battery on the motherboard didn't work, either.

Comment: What other USB devices do you have connected? Does the keyboard work if you disconnect all other USB devices? Type lsusb in terminal, and post the result here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found an answer to this, and never got the keyboard to work in grub. I think the issue may have been related to the fact that it was a dual-boot system.  When I reinstalled Ubuntu over the top of the previous Windows and Ubuntu installations, I found the keyboard worked fine in grub again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I have a logitech wireless keyboard mk700/mk710 and in the grub screen it will not allow me to use it, I enable in the BIOS EHCI handoff and the keyboard started to work after a reboot.

Comment: why don't you state the steps you followed to achieve this.